# nginx remove component from url

Tags: nginx, redirect

Trying to get my site to remove a subfolder from the domain, for example:

example.com.au/moodle/test/pdf

would become

example.com.au/test/pdf

Trying to basically remove the moodle component from any url. Below is what I am currently using, it is not working.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com.au;
  location /moodle {
      rewrite ^/moodle(/.*)$ $1 last;
  }
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong. I have reloaded and restarted the nginx so there must be something wrong with my block.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "something is wrong"? What exactly happens? What do the logs say? Can you somehow see the request that Nginx makes as a result of this rewrite?

Comment: Access log when I try and access:  103.249.67.130 - - [20/Jun/2017:02:55:27 +0000] "GET /moodle/log HTTP/1.1" 404 580 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4)

Comment: "something is wrong" simply means nothing is happening.

Comment: Please don't provide information in comments, it's difficult to read. Please edit your question to provide more information in context with your original question. Also, think about what you find - for example that 404 "not found" is fairly clear. You may want to use command like inotifywait which tells you where Nginx is trying to read the file from. If you want help you do need to be precise, give relevant information, and help us to help you.

Comment: Please show the complete `server` configuration for this virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first off you don't specify your root there, I'm unsure if you've just left it out for the sake of brevity or if it's just not there at all. Try something like this (don't forget to reload nginx config).

The root directive specifies the location where the web facing files are. By setting it to the moodle directory itself, moodle should no longer appear in your url, as all requests will already be directed at it internally.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com.au;

  root /path/to/moodle/web/root;
}
```

The rewrite, should you need it, should be along the lines of:

```
location /moodle {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host/$1$is_args$query_string;
}
```

If this doesn't work, could you provide your entire site config.